# What's the practical limit for the data length of UDP packet?

Tags: sockets, udp, ip

This is wikipedia's explanation of the length field of the UDP header:

> Length
>   A field that specifies the length in bytes of the UDP header
>   and UDP data. The minimum length is 8 bytes because that is the length
>   of the header. The field size sets a theoretical limit of 65,535 bytes
>   (8 byte header + 65,527 bytes of data) for a UDP datagram. The
>   practical limit for the data length which is imposed by the underlying
>   IPv4 protocol is 65,507 bytes (65,535 − 8 byte UDP header − 20 byte IP
>   header).

The practical limit for the data length should minus 20 byte IP header, why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a good look at the explanation of the IP header at this link :
https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt

I quote :
Total Length:  16 bits

> Total Length is the length of the datagram, measured in octets, including internet header and data.  This field allows the length of a datagram to be up to 65,535 octets.  Such long datagrams are impractical for most hosts and networks.  All hosts must be prepared to accept datagrams of up to 576 octets (whether they arrive whole or in fragments).  It is recommended that hosts only send datagrams larger than 576 octets if they have assurance that the destination is prepared to accept the larger datagrams.
>   The number 576 is selected to allow a reasonable sized data block to be transmitted in addition to the required header information.  For example, this size allows a data block of 512 octets plus 64 header octets to fit in a datagram.  The maximal internet header is 60 octets, and a typical internet header is 20 octets, allowing a margin for headers of higher level protocols.

So the maximum total length is 65535 but this includes the IP header itself.
Therefore you have an IP payload that can be 65535 - 20 = 65515.

But the payload of IP in your case is UDP and UDP has a header of its own which is 8 bytes. Hence you get to the `theoretical` limit of the payload of a UDP packet : 65,535 − 8 byte UDP header − 20 byte IP header

Note the use of theoretical instead of practical. The practical limit of a UDP packet takes into account the probability of fragmentation and thus considers the mtu of the network layer. The link above also has an interesting sentence containing the value 576. 576 - 20 - 8 = 548 which is not quite 534 but getting close. This might explain this practical limit.

Comment: You should really be quoting. RFCs, not Wikipedia. The relevant citation is RFC 1122 #3.3.

Comment: Thanks! I got it, IP header's length field is 16-bits long too, that expains everything!

Answer (score 1):

Because UDP packets are encapsulated in IP packets which headers are 20 bytes. You can't send UDP packets without a encapsulated IP packet. Usually the actual limit is way less and it depends on the MTU of the routers between the two endpoints transmitting the UDP packet.

Comment: the length field is in udp's header, why should it contain ip's header length?

Comment: It doesn't contain IP's packet header lenght. IP's header length is fixed: 20 bytes.

Comment: so, why it should minus IP's packet header, not ethernet frame's header length?

Comment: Do you know the 7 network layers?  Don't get the layers mixed up.  Ethernet Frame is a different layer from IP layer.  The IP is embedded in the Ethernet frame.

Comment: @VincentXue Because the IP length word  includes the IP header but not the encapsulating network frame, whatever it may be.

Answer (score 1):

Because the IP header has to be (a) sent and (b) counted in the 16-bit length word. See [RFC 791 #3.1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt).

However the *real* practical limit is generally accepted to be 534 bytes, to avoid fragmentation at the IP layer, which increases the risk of datagram loss.

Comment: The length of IP header has to be counted in UDP header's length field? why?

Comment: It doesn't. It has to be counted in the IP header's length field.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source somewhere that documents this 534 ? I haven't found it yet. I know TCP tries to fill (nagle) up to the mtu, so this value of 534 is odd to me, where does it come from. Why 534 ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck It is based somehow on the 576 non-fragmenting size that is mentioned in either RFC 791 or RFC 1122 and friends. But 576-28=548 so it has never actually made sense to me. But I keep stumbling over it everywhere so I just parrot it mindlessly. NB not the bit you quoted: somewhere else there is a requirement about not fragmenting packets below a certain size. Maybe that isn't 576.