# MTU is limited with RHEL7 on Qt 5.5

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I am trying to do a data transfer over a wired network from one node to the other.

The sender node is running windows while the receiver is running RHEL7. 
I have checked that the same packet is being received on RHEL6 properly (Qt 4.8). Also, a C++ socket on RHEL7 is also able to receive the data flawlessly. 
But when the same data is received on the RHEL7 machine via Qt(tried 4.4, 4.8 and 5.5) UDP socket, the socket is not picking any data larger than 65535 bytes.

Increasing the MTU for the interface does not provide any help. I have not found any file in Qt stating any MTU limit either.

Would love for some advice regarding the same.

P.S I was using broadcast receiver for receiving the data while sending near gibberish on the sender and printing the packet size received.

Comment: It would help if you add some code...

Comment: While this has nothing to do with your actual problem, MTU size is limited by hardware, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit Also, it is impossible to receive single packets larger than 64KiB, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150563/whats-the-practical-limit-for-the-data-length-of-udp-packet It might help a great deal to see both your working and non-working code.

Comment: For code I stated I was using universal broadcast receiver. Its a example provided in Qt creator 5.5 (I was under the impression it was widely used; guess I was wrong). Link : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-broadcastreceiver-example.html. The sender consists of basically a QByteArray which is sent via QUupSocket.write command (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qudpsocket.html#writeDatagram-2). Also; I read the link provided, but lets say that my requirement is to receive a large packet (>64KiB) (I have no control over the sender in actuality). How can I configure it to be ready to receive a big packt?